# ActionMessages error header and footer equivalent in Spring4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Struts 1.1 to Spring 4 mvc migration project. In struts code action errors are getting displayed in JSP using  the action messages are getting from applicationresources.properties file. This property file has errors.header and errors.footer which will be added for every error message.  What is the equivalent solution in spring mvc to add header and footer for errors.

Kiran